# Secure Connection Failed

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet, browser, ssl

I have this problem with Ubuntu, Windows 7, and Safari on my iPhone. There is some type of network issue.

I can't access a growing number of SSL websites because of a secure connection fail. I tried the following:

- clearing all history
- enabling TLS fallback
- reinstalling firefox
- switching the normal DNS to google's open DNS (8.8.8.8)
- disabling UFW (firewall)
- Using different browsers
- Installing ntp
- Running this command: ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
- Ensuring that ca-certificates is installed and running update-ca-certificates

Example, when I go to https://spark.adobe.com/ this is what happens.

---

**Firefox 52:**

[image]

---

**Ubuntu browser:**

[image]

---

**Chromium:**

[image]

How can I fix this? What can I do to find the source of the problem?

Comment: Are you behind some kind of proxy/transparent proxy?

Comment: No proxy that I know of. By the way, this is my PC at work. Also, I am the network admin.

Comment: I suggest running some command of the `tcpdump port 443` kind before opening one of these sites under some Linux distribution and see if the packets/flags are flowing in a reasonable way, maybe you find some `reset` flags (`[R]`) that might indicate that connection is being reset at some point and you can spot where the culprit is.

Comment: are you connected over a wired or wireless connection? If its a wired connection - could you try changing the cable? Also try pinging those sites to check for packet loss...

Comment: @ Journeyman I tried both wireless and wired.

Comment: @nKn I tried running that commant but nothing appears in the terminal. It just doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cyberoam firewall has a built-in anti-virus. This anti-virus is configured to block all unknown protocols going through port 443. Some websites are configured to send different types of traffic through this port, which the anti-virus may not recognize. To disable this feature:

- Log into cyberoam.
- Click on anti-virus in the side menu.
- Click on http/s.
- Uncheck the option "Deny Unknown Protocol".
- Click apply.

Comment: Or, upgrading the firmware will probably also fix the problem as it would likely add more protocols to the list of recognized protocols going through this port.